# Change pecl's temp directory? (installation issue)

Tags: php, permissions, vps, pecl, pear

I am trying to install `imagick` on a VPS running Centos 5.8. Typically, it's a quick fix, but the hosting provider will not allow (permission is already denied) me to use the typical fix, which is to remount `/var/tmp` as executable, and then remount as non-exec.

I have already run the following commands without error (as expected, gcc is needed):

```
yum install php-pear gcc 
yum install ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel
```

After that, when I run `pecl install imagick` it kicks back that /var/tmp permissions were denied.

Is there a way for me to change the default location from `/var/tmp` to resolve this? Or is there another workaround or something I am missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set a different temporary directory on a filesystem on which you can execute binaries. For instance:

```
mkdir /root/tmp
pecl config-set temp_dir /root/tmp
```

or:

```
pear config-set temp_dir /root/tmp
```

Comment: I ran into a documented bug, that `pecl config-set` does not work, but `pear config-set` does, so once I got past there the setup was fairly easy. For anyone curious, I also ended up doing a wget on imagick and then compiled & made it myself to install, as `pecl` was still returning some compilation errors due to the temp folder's involvement.

Comment: If you update your answer (I can't, it's only a 4 letter edit) so that it says pear config... instead of pecl I'll mark it as correct.

Also, if you compile yourself, you need to add the extension to your php.ini.

Comment: Glad it's working. Enjoy!